# WP7 Popup delays opening when used with locations

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, popup, geolocation

I have the following code:

```
ShowPoup(); 
if (_watcher == null)
{
    _watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
    _watcher.MovementThreshold = 15; // use MovementThreshold to ignore noise in the signal
    _watcher.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(watcher_StatusChanged);
}

if (!_watcher.TryStart(true, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please turn on location services on device under Settings.");
    //HidePopup();
}
```

My problem is that the popup doesn't appear until after the _watcher.TryStart() method returns. The point of the popup is to show a loading overlay to tell the user the app is doing something. It's  pointless to have it show after the work is done, at which point I hide the popup, so the user never sees anything.

I have this popup code throughout the app and this is the first time I've encountered this issue. Even if I call ShowPopup() in a separate method before calling the current method, it still doesn't show until after _watcher starts. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are blocking the UI thread during the TryStart. If you can move the watcher initialization to a background thread (e.g. to the threadpool) then you can keep the display "alive".

Something like:

```
ShowPoup(); 
if (_watcher == null)
{
    _watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
    _watcher.MovementThreshold = 15; // use MovementThreshold to ignore noise in the signal
    _watcher.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(watcher_StatusChanged);
}

System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((ignored) =>
{
    if (!_watcher.TryStart(true, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)))
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            HidePopup();
            MessageBox.Show("Please turn on location services on device under Settings.");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: actually, that code needs another HidePopup() for when the trystart succeeds - but I hope you get the idea!